# Как убрать все элементы из массива с помощью mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Здраствуйте, мне нужно убрать все элементы из массива в коллекции mongodb.

Структура коллекции выглядит следующим образом:

```json
{
    gid: '111111',
    list: [{},{},{}]
}
```

Для ее получения я использую данный код:

```js
const database = await Model.findOrCreate({ gid: '111111' }, { gid: '111111' });

console.log(database.doc.list);
```

Я пытался убирать элементы с помощью `while` и `pop()`, но это сильно бьет по оптимизации кода и я думаю что так менее правильно.

Comment: Ты хочешь удалить все документы из некой коллекции?

Comment: Вот почитай про разные методы работы с данными для `mongoose` - https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/getting-started-with-mongodb-and-mongoose/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203799/mongodb-how-to-delete-clear-an-array-in-an-other-array